# What is a rotating "button" called?

Tags: components

You see them in various stereo systems and such, they are used to simulate a potentiometer. There is no limit to how much you can turn them in either direction and as you turn them they send pulses indicating the direction. What are they called?

Comment: Are you thinking of a rotary encoder?

Comment: ah yes that seems to be it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotary_encoder

> A rotary encoder, also called a shaft encoder, is an electro-mechanical device that converts the angular position or motion of a shaft or axle to an analog or digital code.

There are many different varieties and you'll need to further define your requirements to decide which is best for your needs.

Comment: The encoders in the user interfaces (front panels of stereos and such) are usually of contacting type ([like these](http://www.alps.com/prod/info/E/HTML/Encoder/Incremental/Incremental_list1.html)) or magnetic type.